# The Da Vinci Disappearance

Tags: pc, assassins-creed-brotherhood

I got the PC version last week and completed it. Now I'm wanting to play the DLC The Da Vinci Disappearance.

Everywhere I read it says the PC version includes it. So.. where does it start?

I've long ago finished the main sequences. I'm two Thief missions away from 100% sync (I really suck at running the courses).

Answer (score 6):

Ok, after many hours of searching I found the answer.

You have to launch U-Play and redeem the item. It costs zero points. Once done, start the game again and the icon will appear on the map.

Comment: Thank you, I was going to start this weekend and was wondering how I got to the dlc...